# Creating a Factory with data from other Factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

I'm trying to create a FactoryGirl factory that relies on information being passed from other models on creation. Here is what I have so far:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :completed_set do
    user_id 1
    user_program_id 1
    exercise_id 1
    workout_exercise_id 1
    workout_exercise_set_id 1
    program_id 1
    training_week_id 1
    workout_id 1
    set_number 1
    repetitions 1
    weight 1.5
  end
end
```

The problem is the user_id needs to be an actual user_id, and the same goes for several of the other fields. I can do a before(:create), but I want to be able to call `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:completed_set)`, and that will return the initial values, not the values I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but you can pass attributes directly like so `attributes_for(:model_name, user_id: user.id)` and the same for `create`

Comment: That's an option, but since I'll use the factory several times, I'd prefer to keep everything in the factories model.

Comment: why do you need the real `ids`?

Comment: I don't need real ids, but I do need the ids to relate to the ids of other factories because I make a decision based on what values are submitted with a completed_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations) on associations.

If you have a factory :user you can just do:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :completed_set do
    user
    # ... left out for brevity
  end
end
```

If you don't, you can specifiy the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :completed_set do
    association :user, factory: :special_user
    # ... left out for brevity
  end
end
```

That said: I consider it bad style to use nested factories. It seems like a good idea to solve one specific problem at an early stage of an application. But it most probably introduces unexpected side-effects if you rely on this factory in another test.

In my opinion it is better to build the hierarchy of objects during the setup phase of the tests:

```
def setup
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  @completed_set = FactoryGirl.create(:completed_set, user: user)
end
```

This way you know exactly what objects get created and how they are tied together.

Instead of setting the association user (which Rails establishes by setting the user_id to user.id) you can also directly set the user_id:

```
def setup
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  @completed_set = FactoryGirl.create(:completed_set, user_id: user.id)
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The documentation isn't really clear to me. How do I then set the value of the `user_id` and the `user_program_id` in the factory? In the application I could call `user.id` and `user.current_user_program.id` I'm not sure how to do that based on your answer or the documentation.

Comment: @Arel, factory creates the user for you and sets id. That's why I also think it's bad idea :)

Comment: In this situation I am just setting a bunch of attributes for the factory, and calling them in a spec, and creating the completed_set using `post :create, FactoryGirl. build_stubbed(:completed_set)` but I need to be able to pass ids that relate to other generated records in order to test my model properly.

Comment: @Arel You don't need to explicitly set user_id. If you set the association (given you have a relation set up in the model e.g. belongs_to) to some object, then Rails (or FactoryGirl) know to set the user_id. I'll add an example with user_id.

Comment: I'm trying to set the values when I setup the factory, not on FactoryGirl.create. The way you show wont pass the FactoryGirl linter because I'll get a no method on NilClass error when trying to call on a method on a user that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying. Thanks for the help!